# How could RequireJS be used with a system like Joomla?

Tags: web-applications, joomla, requirejs

This is a theoretical question.

How would RequireJS be used with a system like Joomla with the directory structure (including ability to include scripts from components, plugins, etc)

```
/components/com_something/script/a.js
/components/com_other/script/b.js
```

Or isn't RequireJS suitable for this kind of multi-tiered directory structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use paths config:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/components'
  paths: {
    something: 'com_something/script',
    other: 'com_other/script'
  }
});

require(['something/a', 'other/b'], function(a, b){
  // ...
});
```